# get specific ID from a row

Tags: php, mysqli

The program is a part from a login. At first it reads the database. Afterthen it reads a row until it gets the value of the ID. Then I wanna put that value in a Session.

The problem is when I wanna log in, I get everytime an error message, "wrong email/password".

Where could be the problem? I haven't encrypted the password yet, it will be done after it works everything.

```
 <_?php

if(isset($_POST['sbmt'])){
    $login = mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']));
    $pswd =  mysqli_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['pswd']));
            $id =  $_POST['id'];

           if(validateData($login, $pswd) === true){

                    $_SESSION['logedIn'] = true;

           header("Location: index.php");

            }else{
        $_SESSION['logedIn'] = false;
        echo 'Wrong Email/Password';
    }
}

function validateData($login, $pswd){
    if(strlen($login) > 0 && strlen($pswd) > 0){
        $result = mysqli_query("SELECT id,name FROM register WHERE email='$login' && password='$pswd'") or die(mysqli_error());

               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                             if (isset($_SESSION['logedIn'])) {
                             $_SESSION['logedIn'] = $row['id'];
                             } else {
                               return false;
                               }

                               break;
            echo '<newarial>' . $row['id'] . '</newarial>';  }

                    if($row === false){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }else{  
        return false;
    }
}
?_>_
```

Answer (score 0):

thats because you are checking for session logedIn and it's just not there yet so your function validateData returns false every time

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['logedIn'])) {
                             $_SESSION['logedIn'] = $row['id'];
```

You could do something like this:

```
function validateData($login, $pswd){
    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "database") or die("cannot connect"));

    if(strlen($login) > 0 && strlen($pswd) > 0){
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id,name FROM register WHERE email='$login' && password='$pswd'") or die(mysqli_error());

               if (mysqli_num_rows($result) !=1) {
                   return false;
               }

               $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
               $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['id'];
               $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['name'];
               return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Timur I get the same response when I try to log in.

Comment: @user3578515 you sure you can connect to the db and your table "register" has the right user with the right password? You could try running the query manually and see if it finds anything. I have updated my answer with $link variable

Comment: Timur I checked the table and connection and it works. But unfortunately not in the code.

Comment: Timur I replaced my part with your updated code but now the screen got blank. I think there is a much bigger problem

Comment: @user3578515 you are supposed to **learn** from this code, not just use it mindlessly. Your question ("Write me a code!") is **already** offtopic. Don't make it worse asking for more.

Comment: @user3578515 Yes! Exactly! "to figure out", not to write a ready-to-run code. And the answer does it, explaining where is the problem. So - you have figured it out. Now start writing. If you can't - then you need to learn more

Comment: you dont just replace your code with mine, you still have to make some adjustments. Like @Your Common Sense said we just point you in some direction, and dont just write you a code to copy paste it.